# PostgreSQL 11 - using format to assign to variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have been awake for well beyond my schedule and I have been stuck with this issue for a long time, I don't even know what I am looking for to solve, but I wish to use format to insert values that I'll be using for column names, and then executing it... but it keeps giving me errors no matter how much I try changing it :c

Heres the part that im trying to do something that doesnt work, but i think you get the idea what im trying to achieve

```sql
    ratelimit := EXECUTE format('(SELECT %I
                      FROM users.ratelimits 
                      WHERE user_id = $2)
                     ', $1);
```

and heres the full code for the brave

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION users.consume_ratelimit(_name text,__user_id integer)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE
    PARALLEL UNSAFE
    COST 100
AS $BODY$DECLARE
    ratelimit INTEGER;
    reset_timeout timestamptz;
    premium BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    ratelimit := EXECUTE format('(SELECT %I
                      FROM users.ratelimits 
                      WHERE user_id = $2)
                     ', $1);

    reset_timeout := EXECUTE format('(SELECT %I_refresh 
                      FROM users.ratelimits 
                      WHERE user_id = $2)
                     ', $1);

    premium := (SELECT users.is_premium($2));


    IF premium THEN
        RETURN TRUE;

    ELSIF reset_timeout <= NOW() THEN
        UPDATE users.ratelimits
        SET image_refresh = NOW() + '1 hour'::interval,
            image = DEFAULT
            WHERE user_id = $2;
        RAISE NOTICE 'reset';
        RETURN TRUE;

    ELSE
        IF ratelimit > 0 THEN
            EXECUTE format('UPDATE users.ratelimits
            SET %I = %I - 1
            WHERE user_id = $2', $1, $1);
            RAISE NOTICE 'decrement';
            RETURN TRUE;

        ELSIF ratelimit <= 0 THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'out of credits';
            RETURN FALSE;

        ELSE
            EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO users.ratelimits(user_id) VALUES ($2)
            ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET
                %I = excluded.%I,
                %I_refresh = excluded.%I_refresh', $1, $1, $1, $1);
            RAISE NOTICE 'create';
            RETURN TRUE;

        END IF;
    END IF;
END;$BODY$;
```

Comment: Is it part of function? Can you post whole function code?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev added the full code, but its soo ugly only its own mother could love it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) you need to use `into` together with EXECUTE to store the result into a variable. This can handle multiple columns/variables as well, so you only need a single EXECUTE to get both values.

For clarity you should reference parameters by name, not by position.

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT %I, %I_refresh 
                FROM users.ratelimits WHERE user_id = $1'), 
                _name, _name)
   USING __user_id
   INTO ratelimit, reset_timeout;
```

Note the `$1` inside the string for `format()` is a parameter placeholder used when the SQL statement is executed, and will be replaced with the value of the variable specified in the `USING` clause.

Variable assignment is also more efficient without a SELECT:

```
premium := users.is_premium(__user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `some_var := EXECUTE ...` will not work. Additionally, params inside of an EXECUTE statement are not the same as those in the function - you need to supply them to the execute statement.

I have not tested this, but perhaps

```
-- q declared above as text

q := format('
  SELECT %I
  FROM users.ratelimits 
  WHERE user_id = %s;
', $1, $2);

EXECUTE q INTO ratelimit;
```

will work? I also removed the parens from the query, those are unnecessary and may the problem themselves.

I have tested the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_sum (a int, b int)
RETURNS int
AS $$
DECLARE
  q text; 
  result int;
BEGIN
  q := FORMAT ('SELECT %s + %s', $1, $2);
  EXECUTE q INTO result;
  RETURN result;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

and that does work. If my suggestion above does not work, perhaps you can use the above as a starting point.